# How do I select a specific file to compile using make?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this large directory of .cpp mainfiles, each being separate from each other (sharing no common header files). How can I achieve something like `make test.cpp` where `make` will compile `test.cpp` into an apppropriately named binary (`test`) with all the appropriate compiler tags?

Comment: Use [a pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) like `%: %.cpp` and command like `g++ %^ -o $@`, `make test` will then work.

Comment: If you're lucky you might not even need a `makefile` -- just make use of the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Built_002dIn-Rules) (assuming this is `GNU make`).

Comment: You wouldn't say `make test.cpp`.  `test.cpp` is a file that already exists.  The arguments to `make` are _targets_ that you want to be built.  Have you tried running `make test`?

Comment: How do you do this within Vim (using vim-dispatch), where running :Make will automatically expand to :make test.cpp? Appreciate the help.